# What's "[@]" doing to variable in bash for loop

Tags: bash, syntax

I was looking at how Gentoo's ebuilds are made and I found the following code:

```
_VIM_PLUGIN_ALLOWED_DIRS=(
    after autoload colors compiler doc ftdetect ftplugin indent keymap
    macros plugin spell syntax
)

local d
for d in "${_VIM_PLUGIN_ALLOWED_DIRS[@]}" "${@}"; do
                [[ -d "${d}" ]] || continue
                doins -r "${d}"
            done
```

As far as I am aware, `_VIM_PLUGIN_ALLOWED_DIRS` is a list. `d` is a local variable. 
The thing I don't understand is the `[@]` in `_VIM_PLUGIN_ALLOWED_DIRS[@]`. Normally I would omit the `[@]`, and just make `d` iterate over `_VIM_PLUGIN_ALLOWED_DIRS`'s values.

What is it doing? What's its purpose?

I have never seen `[@]`, nor do I know what the `${@}` does afterwards

PS: `doins` is an external function defined elsewhere

Thanks in advance

Comment: From [Arrays (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#index-arrays): *"Any element of an array may be referenced using ${name[subscript]}. The braces are required to avoid conflicts with the shell’s filename expansion operators. If the subscript is ‘@’ or ‘\*’, the word expands to all members of the array name."*

Comment: And `${@} ${*}` or equivalently `$@ $*` similarly [access the positional parameters _like_ an array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html) (but these are portable to any Bournish or POSIX shell, while only ksh/bash/zsh have named arrays).

Comment: "just make "d" iterate over "_VIM_PLUGIN_ALLOWED_DIRS"'s values" How do you manage this magic?

Comment: Regarding `As far as I am aware, _VIM_PLUGIN_ALLOWED_DIRS is a list.` - there are no lists in bash, it's an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Normally I would omit the [@], and just make d iterate over _VIM_PLUGIN_ALLOWED_DIRS's values.

In ksh-style arrays that Bash also has, referencing the array without an index would only give the element at index `0`. This is different from zsh, where referencing an array with an index would give all (non-empty) elements.

The special index `@` is used to get all elements of the arrays as distinct fields. `$@` similarly expands to all the positional parameters (arguments to the script or function).

E.g.

```
arr=(foo "bar doo")
printf "<%s> " "$arr"; echo       # '<foo>'
printf "<%s> " "${arr[@]}"; echo  # '<foo> <bar doo>'
```

Note that in both cases you should quote `"${arr[@]}"` and `"$@"` to avoid word splitting and globbing from inevitably messing up the values.

See:

- [BashGuide on Arrays](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)
- [Arrays in the Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#index-arrays)